# Python: how to explain 0==0<1 return True

Tags: python

In Python
`0==0<1`
returns True
If i use 
`(0==0)<1`
 or 
`0==(0<1)`
it will return False.

So how understand this sentence.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible unless I'm grossly misunderstanding what you're illustrating, no it doesn't

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 No. The correct interpretation would be `0 == 0 and 0 < 1`, which both evaluate to True leading to the final True result.

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it